# What are the commands to reset and fix the boot Records?

Tags: windows

I've messed up my PC and I want to reset the boot records of the Windows Boot Loader. I'm in Command Prompt but I don't know what to command and so on. Please help me out!

Comment: command prompt of what? do you mean the recovery console? What exactly did you do? What OSes do you have loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try entering these commands:

- BootRec.exe /fixmbr
- BootRec.exe /fixboot